# Ruby on Rails MySQL socket from Environment

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I hate having the path to the MySQL socket hard-coded into my Rails YAML files.  It tends to break things if you want to run the app on a bunch of different systems for development.  Is there any official way I can get it to use an environment variable or similar?  Currently I use this:

```
diff --git a/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb b/vendor/rails/activerecord/
index 69e97b9..992387c 100644
--- a/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb
+++ b/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb
@@ -50,7 +50,7 @@ module ActiveRecord
       config = config.symbolize_keys
       host     = config[:host]
       port     = config[:port]
-      socket   = config[:socket]
+      socket   = ENV['MYSQL_SOCK'] || config[:socket]
       username = config[:username] ? config[:username].to_s : 'root'
       password = config[:password].to_s
       database = config[:database]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a different database.yml file for every system since it shouldn't be checked into your VCS.

Comment: I usually package a `database.example.yml` file for this very reason.

Comment: But what if I want it in my VCS?  I want to keep my configuration version controlled.

Comment: @singpolyma What's your reasoning for keeping the configuration versioned? It's bad practice to use the same database.yml file for all your systems. The biggest reason is that you have passwords in there. I would recommend @tadman's suggestion to have a versioned database.example.yml template and then just create the actual file based on this for each system.

Comment: Well, this particular project is internal to my company, and only goes in our private VCS, so passwords aren't a problem.  We actually use git for our deploys, so everything needs to be in git.